# Error al aplicar el pase a una cadena JSON en NodeJS

Tags: javascript, array, nodejs, json, jsonarray

Muy buenas amigos, Quisiera saber si me pueden orientar, tengo  un script de python que regresa una cadena JSON la cual es esta:

```
[
  { "id_checador": 5, "fecha": 2022-12-20 14:19:34, "no_checador": 1 },
  { "id_checador": 5, "fecha": 2022-12-20 14:56:42, "no_checador": 1 },
  { "id_checador": 5, "fecha": 2023-01-27 17:36:58, "no_checador": 1 },
  { "id_checador": 5, "fecha": 2023-01-28 08:42:09, "no_checador": 1 },
  { "id_checador": 5, "fecha": 2023-01-28 13:32:27, "no_checador": 1 },
  { "id_checador": 5, "fecha": 2023-01-30 08:32:40, "no_checador": 1 },
  { "id_checador": 5, "fecha": 2023-01-30 08:32:40, "no_checador": 1 },
];
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, el detalle es que al aplicarle las siguientes lineas:

```
console.log(stdout);
var json2=JSON.parse(stdout);
```

Ya que me da el siguiente error en consola:

```
0|API  | SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 30
0|API  |     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
0|API  |     at /var/www/html/conf/routes.js:1055:24
0|API  |     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:7)
0|API  |     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
0|API  |     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1051:16)
0|API  |     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
```

no se si estoy haciendo algo mal desde el formato del json o tengo que preparar de otra forma la cadena que me arroja el script, si alguien pudiese orientarme se lo agradeceria.

Espero respuestas, muchas gracias.

Comment: El error se puede ver directamente en el primer elemento del array del JSON: `{"id_checador":5,"fecha":2022-12-20 14:19:34,"no_checador":1}` la fecha no tiene un formato JSON válido. Debería estar entre comillas (ser una cadena de texto) `[{"id_checador":5,"fecha":"2022-12-20 14:19:34","no_checador":1}` Puedes leer más sobre JSON aquí: https://www.json.org/json-es.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se encuentra en la forma en la que estás mandando la fecha, ya que JSON no la reconoce dentro del estándar, esto se puede solucionar mandando la fecha como un string (cadena de caracteres) que luego pueda ser manejada por Date.parse().

Auí podrás encontrar algunas opciones [Opciones de formato de fecha en texto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

En tu caso específico se solucionaría utilizando la siguiente forma: "2011-10-10T14:48:00" (date-time form).